# How to Change individual strings in an array of strings in C?

Tags: c

I have pasted an example variable below so that I can point out what I need to change. If you look there is four strings in this array how do I change one (non-manual) of the letters of one of the strings. If anyone can solve this I would appreciate it very much.

```
char *names[] = {
               "bill",
               "man",
              "test",
              "bob",
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by non manual ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is an array of pointers, each pointing to a string literal. Modifying string literal is not allowed in standard C and doing so is [*undefined behaviour*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Depending on your usage and need, 1) you may take a copy of the string and modify it or 2) declare `names` as an array of arrays (instead of pointers) and modify the array element.

Comment: How do I create an array of an array.

Comment: An example: `char names[][10] = { ..};`

Comment: An easy way would be to declare `char names[][10] = {...}`. This will, of course, limit your strings to nine characters. (10 minis one for the null terminator.)

Comment: An example: `char names[][10] = {"bill",  "man", "test", "bob"};`. This creates an array of 4 arrays, each can hold upto 10 chars (You need to reserve 1 byte out 10 for NUL char if you intend to use them as "string"). Also note, you can't "insert" another array into the array for which you need to more work. And you have to ensure your arrays don't go beyond the boundaries (10 bytes in this example) as C doesn't do that.

Comment: Is there any other way

Comment: @user3600107 With array declaration, you can change any char. e.g. `names[0][0]='m';` will change `names[0]` to `"mill"`. If you want to insert more chars at a position then you have to do the "move" yourself.

Comment: **   char names[0][10] = {"bill", "man", "test", "bob"};
     names[0][0]='m';
      printf("%s ", names[0][4]); ** This code only crashes my program

Comment: It could crash for any problem in your code. The problem I see in the line you posted is that `names[0][4]` is a *char* not a *string*. So if you want to print the 1st string then do: `printf("%s", names[0]);`. If you want to print the 1st char in the 1st string then do:`printf("%c", names[0][0]);` (notice the format specifier). names[0][4] is the 5th char in the 1st string, which is NUL (a non-printable char). Remember array indexes start from 0 in C, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

To change "bill" to "ball" in your example I think this would do it:

```
names[0][1] = 'a';
```

Comment: I just tried that and would have expected it to work, but instead the program just crashes as soon as it encounters that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use sizeof() and pointers to do it, since every char in memory is linear

**Eg:**
`

```
//Remove duplicate char in string 'in'
char* rem_dup(char* in){

    int i=0, j=0, pos=0;
    for(;i<strlen(in);i++){
    int charat = *(in+i);
    for(j=i+1;j<strlen(in);j++){
        if(charat == *(in+j)){
        *(in+i) = *(in+j) = -1;
        }
    }

    if(*(in+i) > 0){        
        *(in+pos) = *(in+i);
        pos++;
    }

    }

    *(in+pos) = 0;
    return in;
}

int main(){
    int i=0;
    char str[][100] = {"remove duplicates", "", "aabb", "ab", "a", "abba"};
    for(;i<sizeof(str)/sizeof(char);i+=sizeof(str[0])/sizeof(char)){
    printf("IN :%s\n",(char*)str+i);
    printf("OUT:%s\n", rem_dup((char*)str+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`